# Two value same constructors getting error [ANDROID]

Tags: android, constructor

Why I cannot set two constructors with same argument (String, String, int)? But in my case has to be apply different values, such as A activity input accNo, phoneNo and amount, B activity input accNo, billNo, amount.

In android studio it prompt the error:

> ***Bill(String, String, int) already defined***

```
public class Bill {

String acc_no;
String bill_no;
String phone_no;
int amount_;

public Bill() {

}

public Bill(String acc_no, String bill_no, String phone_no, int amount_) {
    this.setAcc_no(acc_no);
    this.setBill_no(bill_no);
    this.setPhone_no(phone_no);
    this.setAmount_(amount_);
}

public Bill(String acc_no, String phone_no, int amount_) {
    this.acc_no = acc_no;
    this.phone_no = phone_no;
    this.amount_ = amount_;
}

public Bill(String acc_no, String bill_no, int amount_) {
    this.acc_no = acc_no;
    this.bill_no = bill_no;
    this.amount_ = amount_;
}


public Bill(String acc_no, int amount_) {
    this.setAcc_no(acc_no);
    this.setAmount_(amount_);
}


public String getAcc_no() {
    return acc_no;
}

public void setAcc_no(String acc_no) {
    this.acc_no = acc_no;
}

public String getBill_no() {
    return bill_no;
}

public void setBill_no(String bill_no) {
    this.bill_no = bill_no;
}

public String getPhone_no() {
    return phone_no;
}

public void setPhone_no(String phone_no) {
    this.phone_no = phone_no;
}

public int getAmount_() {
    return amount_;
}

public void setAmount_(int amount_) {
    this.amount_ = amount_;
}
```

Comment: It is a basic rule of Constructor and methods. We can create with different parameters with the same name but we can't create with same parameters with same name.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have 2 constructors with the same signature (or erasure). A possible workaround would be using a no-args constructor & an instance method to do exactly what you need:

```
Bill bill = new Bill();
bill.method1(acc_no, phone_no, amount);
bill.method2(acc_no, bill_no, amount);

public method1(String acc_no, String phone_no, int amount_) {
    this.acc_no = acc_no;
    this.phone_no = phone_no;
    this.amount_ = amount_;
}

public method2(String acc_no, String bill_no, int amount_) {
    this.acc_no = acc_no;
    this.bill_no = bill_no;
    this.amount_ = amount_;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't have two same constructors, no point, however in your case, you can just swap parameters

```
public Bill(String acc_no, String bill_no, int amount_) {
```

to

```
public Bill(String acc_no, int amount_ ,String bill_no) {
```

Comment: if I change to 
public Bill(String acc_no, int amount_ ,String bill_no) {
it won't affect the input value? Because I have to store those values into SQLite, it won't affect the query when insert data?

Comment: No, since you only swap the parameters of a constructor. The parameter types, that could affect your query stay the same, String and int.

Answer (score 0):

in android you can not set same type of two constructor
but you what this than change sequence of your parameter

below you modify class

```
public class Bill {
    String acc_no;
    String bill_no;
    String phone_no;
    int amount_;

    public Bill() {
    }

    public Bill(String acc_no, String bill_no, String phone_no, int amount_) {
        this.setAcc_no(acc_no);
        this.setBill_no(bill_no);
        this.setPhone_no(phone_no);
        this.setAmount_(amount_);
    }

    public Bill(String acc_no, String phone_no, int amount_) {
        this.acc_no = acc_no;
        this.phone_no = phone_no;
        this.amount_ = amount_;
    }

    public Bill(String acc_no, int amount_, String bill_no) {
        this.acc_no = acc_no;
        this.bill_no = bill_no;
        this.amount_ = amount_;
    }


    public Bill(String acc_no, int amount_) {
        this.setAcc_no(acc_no);
        this.setAmount_(amount_);
    }


    public String getAcc_no() {
        return acc_no;
    }

    public void setAcc_no(String acc_no) {
        this.acc_no = acc_no;
    }

    public String getBill_no() {
        return bill_no;
    }

    public void setBill_no(String bill_no) {
        this.bill_no = bill_no;
    }

    public String getPhone_no() {
        return phone_no;
    }

    public void setPhone_no(String phone_no) {
        this.phone_no = phone_no;
    }

    public int getAmount_() {
        return amount_;
    }

    public void setAmount_(int amount_) {
        this.amount_ = amount_;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define the two constructors with the same name, same return type and same arguments in Java, as it cannot distinguish between their usages and this results in ambiguity.

A possible solution is to add a fourth argument to distinguish between the two constructors. You do **not have to** use this fourth argument though.

```
public Bill(String acc_no, String phone_no, int amount_) {
    this.acc_no = acc_no;
    this.phone_no = phone_no;
    this.amount_ = amount_;
}
public Bill(String acc_no, String bill_no, int amount_, int dummy) {
    this.acc_no = acc_no;
    this.bill_no = bill_no;
    this.amount_ = amount_;
    dummy = 0;
}
```